# Copy data from one worksheet to another worksheet

Tags: excel, vba

I want to copy data from one Excel worksheet to another Excel worksheet.

```vb
Sub CopyInfo()

    On Error GoTo Err_Execute

    Sheet1.Range("A1:J75").Copy
    Sheet2.Range("A1").Rows("1:1").Insert Shift:=xlDown

Err_Execute:

    If Err.Number = 0 Then MsgBox "All have been copied!" Else _
      MsgBox Err.Description

End Sub
```

Comment: What you have done so far?

Comment: I tried with this code but couldn't able copy.this is for one sheet to another sheet. Sub CopyInfo()
    On Error GoTo Err_Execute

    Sheet1.Range("A1:J75").Copy
    Sheet2.Range("A1").Rows("1:1").Insert Shift:=xlDown

Err_Execute:
    If Err.Number = 0 Then MsgBox "All have been copied!" Else _
    MsgBox Err.Description
End Sub


Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

Comment: please edit your question with code

Comment: just tried with this code, couldn't help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is what you are after, there was a mistake in the if statment, if you are doing `If` and `ElseIf` you need to tell it, if it is this then do this or if its not this then if it is this do that. I can explain this in more detail if needed.

```
Sub CopyInfo()

On Error GoTo Err_Execute

Sheet1.Range("A1:J75").Copy
Sheet2.Range("A1").Rows("1:1").Insert Shift:=xlDown

Err_Execute:

If Err.Number = 0 Then

    MsgBox "All have been copied!"

ElseIf Err.Number <> 0 Then

    MsgBox Err.Description

End If

End Sub
```

Hope this helps, leave a comment if you need more info

Comment: Thanks a lot. It worked.                                                         
     1. Is it possible to save into another work book instead of same workbook?                                                                                                                                  2.  Also is it possible to create a name of the sheet by current date?   
Please assist Mr. Burns

Comment: @ranjith , sorry the answers for those questions would be too long to fit into the comment sections here, post a new question for each of those questions and someone may be able to help

Comment: sure.. Thanks Mr. Burns